# Decoding Byte to Original String using DatatypeConverter

Tags: java

I have used MessageDigest to hash my password + salt ,now I want to convert back so that I would get the original value compare with the user password.

```
String _Pass = new String(tfuserpass.getPassword());      
  //===========================================================================================================================================================
  MessageDigest md = null;   
    try
    {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");          
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  md.update(_Pass.getBytes());
  byte byteData[] = md.digest();

  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++)
  {
   sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
  }


Class main()
{

//I have used MessageDigest to hash + salt in this class for password.
}

Class main1()
{
//Now I want to decode and compare the values with the actual value to authenticate the user here.


}
```

How can I authenticate the user?

Comment: You seem to not understand what *hashing* is. It's one-way.

Comment: ok I got it ...but how do I authenticate while Login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a MEssage digest you can not decrypt it, the usual way to do it to take the new password, apply the same salt and hash and compare the resulting value against the original hash.

This way you never store user passwords and if you get hacked users are secured

Comment: Ignoring that SHA hashing is *the wrong way to store passwords* these days, of course.

Comment: agreed, the hash needs to be stored, also looking closely the data is not hashed correctly as i don't see a salt

Comment: Again I have to hash + salt it again to compare at the time of Login?

Comment: @Mehul Rathod Yes I have also noticed that HASH should be random,I get the same HASH value each time I put the same password,doesn't it show me not the same hashed each time again if I use the same password?

Comment: If its a resonalble size project, i wold say use a library like Apache Shiro http://shiro.apache.org/, it would be far more secure then you can ever write

Comment: I know the OP has accepted this answer, and it *does* answer the OP's question. The problem is the OP's question is flawed from the start; **SHA should not be used for storing passwords**. It's simply too easy to brute force.  See: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: I completely agree hence the suggesting to use a proper library then to roll your own.